# How to return checked checkbox after data is stored?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a checkbox list of all my customers in wordpress.

The data is stored into my custom table called wp_assigned_products, I get the post_id(product id), meta_key(customer keyword), meta_value(customer ID) and assigned(yes or no) values saved into the table when a user is is checked and the post is updated.

I cant for the life of me figure out how to return a checked box for the checked users, once the page is reloded.

My checkboxes are all empty but the record is saved to the database table. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction? I have been working on this for hours but keep ending up with a conflict between the meta_value and assigned row. Many thanks.

My code as follows:

```
add_action("admin_init", "users_meta_init");
function users_meta_init(){
    add_meta_box("users-meta", "Assign customers to this product", "users", "product", "normal", "high");
}

function users(){

    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $user_args  = array(
        'role' => 'customer',
        'orderby' => 'display_name'
       );

    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($user_args);
    $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

    if (!empty($authors)) {
        foreach ($authors as $author) {
            $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
            $author_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'users', $author_info->ID);

            echo " <input type='checkbox' name='users' value='$author_info->ID'> $author_info->first_name $author_info->last_name<br/> ";
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_userlist');

function save_userlist($author_id){

    global $wpdb;
    global $post;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post->ID;
        return $author_info->ID;
    }
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "assigned_products";

    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
                      'post_id'    => $post->ID,
                      'meta_key'  => "customer",
                      'meta_value'  => $_POST["users"],
                      'assigned'  => "yes",
                      )
                  );
}
```

Comment: A little bit of sensible code indentation help the readability **and a lot with debugging**

Answer (score 1):

I am not a WP expert by any stretch of the imagination but there are a few obvious woopsees in this code.

This cannot work, only the first return will work, I am surprised you are not getting a compiler warning about unreachable code? Which makes me think you are not looking at your error log!

```
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post->ID;
    return $author_info->ID;
}
```

Also within the scope of that function there is no `$author_info` object to return `$author_info->ID` anyway.

This IF looks a little off!

```
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
```

if `DOING_AUTOSAVE` is defined what is `&& DOING_AUTOSAVE` supposed to be testing, do you mean

```
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && $something == DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
```

Finally the way to set a checkbox to checked is by adding the property `checked="checked"` its attribute list

```
echo " <input checked="checked" type='checkbox' name='users' value='$author_info->ID'> $author_info->first_name $author_info->last_name<br/> ";
```

But I assume you only want to do that IF something == something and that is where my lack of WP knowledge means I cannot see what you might be testing for or against.